# Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive](idk why)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s[101], pal[101];
    cin.getline(s,100);

    for (int i = strlen(s); i >= 0; i--)
        strcat(pal, s[i]);

    if (strcmp(s, pal) == 0)
        cout << "corect";
    else
        cout << "incorect";
    return 0;
}
```

Hello. I tried to verify if a word is a palindrome and it gave me the error:

> "Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]".

It isn't the first time when I encounter this annoying error and I need some help. Can someone explain what's wrong with my code and (please :)) ) give me some article/theory/something to understand why this error occurs?
Thank you and sorry for asking such silly question. I saw it like 1000 times and still don't understand it.

Comment: `strcat` connect two strings, not string and `char`.

Comment: In this line `strcat(pal,s[i]);` s[i] is char not pointer to char, see declaration of strcat - `char * strcat ( char * , const char * );`.

Comment: strcat declaration: char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );

Comment: You could probably solve this a lot easier using `std::string` and [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has already been pointed out the reason you are getting the error is because you are passing a `char` and not a `const char*` to `strcat`.

As the question is marked as `c++` I'll go ahead and show the c++-way of doing this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s, pal;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);

    for (auto it = s.rbegin(), end = s.rend(); it != end; ++it)
        pal.push_back(*it);

    if (s == pal)
        std::cout << "correct" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "incorrect" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prefer std::string to using raw c-style char arrays, and with is comes the use of a [reverse_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) in the loop.

Comment: up for actually using C++. For bonus points, cache the end iterator, stop post-incrementing where not needed (it's at best pointless, possibly even wasteful), and output `'\n'` instead of `std::endl` unless you specifically need to flush the stream. :P That said, the really good way to do this would simply be to use `std::reverse`, but if we assume this is an exercise and part of that is to implement the algorithm manually, it's infinitely better to do that using actual C++ features instead of ugly C hand-me-downs.

Comment: Edited to cache the end iterator, and pre-increment.

Answer (score 2):

Besides obvious error with `strcat` pointed out already, you don't need it as you can populate `pal` array directly. Also when you iterate backwards, you should start with the last character of the string and not null terminator, like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    char s[101], pal[101];

    if (std::cin.getline(s, 100))
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = strlen(s) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            pal[j++] = s[i];

        pal[j] = 0;

        if (strcmp(s, pal) == 0)
            std::cout << "corect";
        else
            std::cout << "incorect";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**And C++ version:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    std::string str;

    if (std::getline(std::cin, str))
        std::cout << (str == std::string(str.crbegin(), str.crend()) ? "corect" : "incorect") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness as the OP was more C wish in style, here is a way of detecting palindromes in C with loops:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_palindrone(const char *str)
    {
    const char *first, *last;
    first=last=str;
    while(*last) last++;
    last--;
    while(first < last && *first==*last) { first++; last--; }
    if(*first==*last) return 1;
    return 0;
    }
```